# How to refresh the main page asynchronously when receiving HTTP Post in generic handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asynchronous

I'm developing a ASP.Net webform application that uses a generic handler to receive HTTP POST and retrieve data from it in order to write them into database and then display it in the GridView control of the main page. I want to make the main page been automatically refreshed once the generic handler receives a HTTP Post, but it can't and I have to click the refresh button on the browser to update its data content. I tried to write some refreshing code in the ProcessRequest method like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //Parse and process data from received HTTP Post
    context.Response.Redirect("~/Main.aspx");
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Response.Redirect("~/Main.aspx?userid=1234&pagestate=5", false);

Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int userid = Request.QueryString["userid"];
     int pagestate = Request.QueryString["pagestate"];

     if(user != 0 && pagestate == 5)
     {
         //configure page for the reloaded state ie. once you reload it with this variable, how is it different to without this variable.
     }
}
```

User the querystring value to determine how the page needs to be set up. Pass through information the 'ProcessRequest' uses and load the page around those values.

I had a similar problem... I solved it by doing what you did above and included a query string variable or 2 to set the page state to what it needed to be.

Comment: Can you give more details for your solution?

Comment: the page state variable lets the page load know that this is coming from a process request as opposed to just a normal page load. You can base the pages flow off that...

Comment: How does the code you provide force the main page to refresh? I don't see  any big difference between your code and that in my question.

Comment: it does exactly what your code does but, it provides the variables in the query string which could be used to set the page in a way that it does what you need. 

You reload the page with those variables. use them to recreate the page in a way that everything that was on it before, is there.

Comment: So, in summary, it does not refresh the page. It reloads it with instructions to get back to where you were previously.

Comment: Actually I want the main page been refreshed when receving HTTP request so that it can present the updated data to user immediately. In your code, the page is reloaded, but can not be refreshed.

Comment: Are you unable to send variables with the request? To force the page layout to be how you need it to be?

Comment: `send variables with the request` I don't get it. Anyway the main page doesn't show the updated content when I run the code you provide. It does only when I click the refresh button on the broswer.